# jQuery mobile anatomy mixed with full sized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to use the same HTML markup for both mobile and full size viewing modes. Do you think I should follow jQuery mobile's anatomy convention regardless? Eg. data-role="page", etc. mixed with full-size markup

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [responsive themes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) regardless using jquery or anything.

> Responsive web design (RWD) is a web design approach aimed at crafting
>   sites to provide an optimal viewing experience—easy reading and
>   navigation with a minimum of resizing, panning, and scrolling—across a
>   wide range of devices (from mobile phones to desktop computer
>   monitors)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should go for CSS3 to handle page layout for your targeted screen sizes. jQuery mobile will not get fit for desktop view(UI look and feel). go for different styling for desktop view and mobile view.

Answer (score 0):

jquery mobile is a framework that makes webpages look like native apps.
You use it to enhance your 'standard' HTML based webpages, so it's like adding on another layer to your webpage that makes it feel and operate like a native mobile app.

It is possible to use it for both desktop and mobile browsers, and for simple implementations even use the same basecode to do this.

See Mobile Graded Browser Support here for supported browsers:
http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/

Also the HTML markup used on mobile browsers and desktop browsers is the same markup, so technically there is no 'full-size markup'.
jquery mobile Enhances HTML, it is not a replacement for it.